# Weird graphical errors in console and on computer shut down

Tags: 11.10, virtual-console

I am all new to Ubuntu (and Linux in general) and I am experiencing some strange graphic on my screen.

Console #1 (ctrl+alt+f1):

[image]

Exactly the same happens on all the other consoles (2-6), and the consoles don't seem to work. And I see the same when I hibernate or shut down my computer, but not when I suspend it.

I was thinking that it may have something to do with the SiS 671 video driver work around that I use? http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11476910&postcount=773

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Perhaps I should add that I can simply exit the console (alt+f7) from where I can use the computer normally.

Comment: Did you try the ppa in the forums link you gave ?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the ppa from the above forums link

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:acasagrande/xf86-video-sismedia
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-sismedia
```

Then reboot.